# Tilde below letter + subscript creates unwanted spacing

Tags: amsmath, subscripts, tilde

I use a tilde below a letter as a symbol for a vector. Redefining the \vec-command delivers a good output, but subscripts are a pain.
I'm using the following code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{{\underset{\sim}{#1}}}
$\vec v = \vec{e}_x + 2 \vec{e}_y + 3\vec{e}_z $
\end{document}
```

This produces the following output:

[image: bad output]

The space between the symbol and the tilde is too big and the subscript for the unit vectors is too low.

I'd like this better:

[image: good output]

I already tried multiple variations, e.g. `{\vec{e}}_x`, but the problem persists.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You maybe want to use `accents`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{accents}

\newcommand{\ut}[1]{\underaccent{\tilde}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\ut{#1}}

\begin{document}

$\vec v = \vec{e}_x + 2 \vec{e}_y + 3\vec{e}_z $

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @jaytar On the other hand, there are better ways for denoting vectors, for instance with `\mathbf` or `\bm`.

Comment: I guess that depends on personal preference. I also like bold font for vectors, but I have to use the tilde notation. This is especially helpful for tensors of different dimensions, so a one-dimensional tensor is a tilde, a two-dimensional tensor has two tildes etc. This doesn't work for bold as vector notation.

Answer (score 8):

A `stackengine` solution.  The underset gap can be adjusted with the 1st argument to `\stackengine`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,stackengine}
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{%
  \smash{\ensurestackMath{\stackengine{1pt}{#1}{\scriptscriptstyle\sim}{U}{c}{F}{F}{S}}}
  \vphantom{#1}
}
\begin{document}
$\vec v = \vec{e}_x + 2 \vec{e}_y + 3\vec{e}_z $
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Try the same using `undertilde` package.

The code is as follows. It works for me perfectly.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{undertilde}
\begin{document}
$\utilde{v} = \utilde{e}_{x} + 2 \utilde{e}_{y} + 3\utilde{e}_{z}$ 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfectly may be a bit of a stretch, considering the tilde collides with the subset _x_.

Comment: I guess `{\utilde e}_x` would fix that but put the x too low for your taste, so you might want to `\smash{...}` it

Comment: (Then actually the x might be too far, but I see no way to do better with this `\utilde` which is slightly too wide for a single character. Logically, what you do have is `\utilde{e_x}`, because the index x does not apply to `{\utilde e}` but rather the `\utilde` applies to the vector `{e_x}` as an entity.